# How to exit when I get any result from a thread pool in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code to web scraping.I use concurrent.futures to speed it up.But there is a problem I don't know how to solve.

```
import logging
import json
import requests
import re
from lxml import etree
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

def chem960(cas_no = str(64173962),time_out=(10,20)):
    #logging.info("start chem960")
    try:
        r = requests.get("http://www.chem960.com/structure/sc{cas_no}".format(cas_no=cas_no),timeout=time_out)
        root = etree.HTML(r.text)
        selector = "/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]/text()"
        smiles_key = root.xpath(selector)
        smiles = smiles_key[1].strip()
        logging.info("finish chem960")
        return {"smiles":smiles,"source":"chem960"}
    except:
        logging.info("finish chem960")
        return {"source":"chem960"}

def chemexper(cas_no = "2040906",time_out=(10,20)):
    #logging.info("start chemexper")
    try:
        url = "http://www.chemexper.com/searchResult.shtml?format=ccd2013%2Cccd&target=structure&options=brandqtyoffercrm&searchValue="+cas_no+"&searchTemplate=rn.value%3D%22%3F%22&Search=Search"
        start_html = requests.get(url,timeout=time_out).text
        #logging.info(start_html)
        index_link = re.findall('<iframe id="searchResultsFrame"  src="(.*?)">',start_html)
        index_link = index_link[0]
        index_html = requests.get(index_link,timeout=time_out).text
        #logging.info(index_html)
        final_url = re.findall('<a href="(.*?)">here</a>',index_html)
        final_url = "http://newsearch.chemexper.com/"+final_url[0]
        final_html = requests.get(final_url,timeout=time_out).text
        #logging.info(final_html)
        root = etree.HTML(final_html)
        #InChI = root.xpath('/html/body/table[1]//tr[2]/td[1]/table//tr[1]/td/text()')[1].strip()
        InChIKey =root.xpath('/html/body/table[1]//tr[2]/td[1]/table//tr[2]/td/text()')[0]

        #logging.info("finish chemexper")
        return {"InChIKey":InChIKey,"source":"chemexper"}
    except:
        logging.info("finish chemexper")
        return {"source":"chemexper"}

def ncbi(cas_no = "2040906",time_out=(10,20)):
    #logging.info("start ncbi")
    try:
        url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pccompound?term="+cas_no
        start_html = requests.get(url,timeout=time_out).text
        findword = "(https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/\d{5,10})"
        pattern = re.compile(findword)
        results = [i.split('/')[-1] for i in pattern.findall(start_html)]
        pid = results[0]
        pull_url = "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug_view/data/compound/"+str(pid)+"/JSON/?"
        index_html = requests.get(pull_url,timeout=time_out).text
        root = json.loads(index_html)
        smiles = root['Record']['Section'][2]['Section'][1]['Section'][3]['Information'][0]['StringValue']
        logging.info("finish ncbi")
        return {"smiles":smiles,"source":"ncbi"}
    except:
        logging.info("finish ncbi")
        return {"source":"ncbi"}
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cas_no = "2040906"
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as pools:
        data = [pools.submit(chem960,cas_no),pools.submit(chemexper,cas_no),pools.submit(ncbi,cas_no)]
    data = [i.result() for i in data]
```

I want to exit and destory the thread pool if any pools.submit has got result.How should I modify my code.Does ThreadPoolExecutor has any method to make it?

Comment: Hey DachuanZhao, do we really need all this code for the question? The fundamental issue seems to be how to only wait for the first thread in a pool to finish, right?

Comment: yes.I give all the code in order that you can copy and run it conveniently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
concurrent.futures.wait(data,return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
pools.shutdown(wait=False)
```

Comment: I add it to the next line of "data = [pools.submit(chem960,cas_no),pools.submit(chemexper,cas_no),pools.submit(ncbi,cas_no)]",and it doesn't work...

Comment: Using a `with` block with an executor automatically calls `.shutdown(wait=True)`. Try it without with block. Also .wait() returns which future is done. Check results.done[0].